# Is there any way to embed an activity in ViewGroup? Or to convert an Activity into a View?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building an app that has a main `Activity` that takes advantage of the Android `ViewGroup` element. I have been able to add `ListView`s to the `ViewGroup` using the instantiateItem() method of the `PagerAdapter` and it's all working well. I also have a separate `Activity` that I'm using to display information that is built using a `RelativeLayout`. In other words it's a full-blown activity. Of course, both Activities work perfectly and the app is set up so that currently you can currently switch between them perfectly using simple `Intent`s.

My question is how do I embed the functionality and layout of second activity in the first activity? I want to put the first `Activity` in one of the `View`s of the `ViewGroup` `Activity`.  From what I think I understand, the `PagerAdapter` only accepts views as "instantiable" items and so I'd have to find some way to convert my `Activity` to a `View`. So I might have to make it into a custom `View`? But then how would I define its layout and its methods?

To recap:

`Activity1` is a ViewGroup activity that already contains multiple `ListViews`.

`Activity2` is a regular activity that is built using an XML layout with its root layout as `RelativeLayout`.

I want to embed the entire functionality and layout of `Activity2` into one of the `Views` of `Activity1`.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is called an ActivityGroup, which has been replaced with Fragment in API 11. [Here](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010_09_01_archive.html) is a tutorial on using a TabActivity, which is an ActivityGroup.

I think you should be very cautious about doing this though... Activities are meant to represent a single screen for a reason. That way the OS can free resources more easily and so performance is improved.

If you are targeting an API higher than 11, (e.g. Android 3.0+) [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) is the official guide about [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html).

I assume that Fragments are a much better solution than ActivityGroups, since they are a platform highlight of honeycomb.

Comment: Don't forget the Fragment's were included in the compatibility library so they now are supported all the way back to 1.6

Comment: I was not aware of that, very interesting

Comment: So as long as I am using the compatibility library (which I already am to use `ViewGroup`) I can use Fragments as well!?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks to all three of you.

Comment: For future reference to anyone else, I meant `ViewPager`, not `ViewGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) for this. No doubt about it. You can use fragments for lower API levels via the android [Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).